# With Angular Universal, how to mix the pre-rendering and dynamic SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am looking to add SSR to my existing angular app. What I want to achieve is to make the app partially pre-rendering, and another part (with dynamic routes) to be dynamic SSR rendered using universal SSR.
There seems no out of box way to do that. I could add some code to server.ts to handle the pre-rendering routes and return them from "dist" folder.
But wondering whether there is a better option?

Comment: Could you please clear what do you exactly mean by partial pre rendering? Is it something like you want a portion of a page to be particularly prerendered or you want to prerender some pages and want other pages to be directly served from the server